# Patch Request Method in Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

For update I use the following code that works:

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateProduct(req.body); 
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
    { 
     name: req.body.name,
     description: req.body.description,
     category: req.body.category,
     tags: req.body.tags,
     withdrawn: req.body.withdrawn,
     extraData: {
       brand: req.body.extraData.brand,
       quantity: req.body.extraData.quantity,
       type: req.body.extraData.type
     } 
   }, 
   {new: true}
  );

  if (!product) return res.status(404).send('The product with the given ID was not found.');

  res.send(product);
});
```

What I want to do is to create a Patch operation that updates only certain fields and not all of them as the update above. These fields are not standard but they are one of the above fields of the update operation.

Comment: So...only pass the fields you need updated and remove the `{new: true}` flag  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @James I dont know the fields that are going to be filled. i.e the client may update only the name or something else.

Comment: yeah so those fields would be coming from the client and, based on your current example, are a 1:1 field mapping so `findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)`.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't change anything. I just returns the json document

Comment: @James So I added the {new: true} in the end and works just fine. Thank you for your answer ,too!

Comment: Why does this happen? Mongoose docs say "if you don't include any update operators in update, Mongoose will wrap update in $set for you" Any clue? Thank you in advance and regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this snippet (didn't test it locally though). The idea is to only update those fields in Product, which were mentioned in req.body. Be sure your validator is secure, otherwise you can end up with nosql injection.

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateProduct(req.body); 
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).exec();
  if (!product) return res.status(404).send('The product with the given ID was not found.');

  let query = {$set: {}};
  for (let key in req.body) {
    if (product[key] && product[key] !== req.body[key]) // if the field we have in req.body exists, we're gonna update it
       query.$set[key] = req.body[key];

  const updatedProduct = await Product.updateOne({_id: req.params.id}, query}).exec();

  res.send(product);
});
```

Also I'm sure you can leverage lodash in the line, where I you use a for-in loop ;)

The downside of this approach is that it takes 2 queries to mongo, because you need a real document to compare the thing. Also update operation doesn't trigger post save hooks of your model. If you need them -  you should findById() first, update necessary fields and then hit .save() on the very document you found.
Hope it helps

Comment: I get this error ''TypeError: Product.findById(...).exec(...).toObject is not a function''

Comment: I changed your code a little bit and also put the patch method and it works. Thank you for your help, too!

Comment: Brilliant answer! Just remove the the closing braces after query, so it should be:

const updatedProduct = await Product.updateOne({_id: req.params.id}, query).exec();

or 

const updatedProduct = await Product.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, query})

for the new versions of mongoose, no exec() required.

Answer (score 0):

```
        You could do this as well:
        // define your middlewares here
       // validateObjectId.js
        const mongoose = require('mongoose');
        module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
            if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
                return res.status(404).send("Invalid ID.");
            next();
        }
        
    // 404.js 
    module.exports = function (str, id) {
        if (!str || !id) throw new Error('the string name and id must be defined');
        return `The ${str} with the given ID (${id}) was not found`;
    }
// import your middlewares into your product route
       const validateObjectId = require('../middleware/validateObjectId'); // respect your middleware path
       const fourOfour = require('../middleware/404'); // respect your middleware path
            
       router.put('/:id', validateObjectId, async (req, res) => {
            const { error } = validateProduct(req.body);
            const { name, description, category, tags, withdrawn, extraData, } = req.body
            if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
        
            let product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).exec();
            if (!product) return res.status(404).send(fourOfour("Product", req.params.id));
            product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
                name: name || product.name,
                description: description || product.description,
                category: category || product.category,
                withdrawn: withdrawn || product.withdrawn,
               extraData: extraData || product.extraData
            }, { new: true });
            product = await product.save();
           if (!product) return res.status(404).send(fourOfour("Product", req.params.id));
            res.send(product);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

***I want to update a specific article in articles collection so i used patch method instead of put method.***
***The only part that is been changed is there in (req.body)***

app.route("/articles").patch(function (req, res) {

```
    console.log(req.body)

    Article.updateOne(
        { title: req.params.articleName },
        { $set: req.body }
    ).then(foundArticle => {
        res.send("Succesfully article updated specifically");
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error is: " + err);
    });

})
```